# Trouble installing Ganache-UI - Shoots out an error that specifies to rename a file that does not exist on my computer

Tags: github, installation, blockchain, ethereum, ganache

`PLATFORM: win32
GANACHE VERSION: 2.5.4

EXCEPTION:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\amazi\AppData\Roaming\Ganache\global\Settings.3688509284' -> 'C:\Users\amazi\AppData\Roaming\Ganache\global\Settings'
at Object.renameSync (fs.js:643:3)
at writeFileSync (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\app.asar\node_modules\write-file-atomic\index.js:124:8)
at Proxy.setItem (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-localstorage\LocalStorage.js:217:7)
at JsonStorage_JsonStorage.setToStorage (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\app.asar\webpack:\src\main\types\json\JsonStorage.js:48:18)
at JsonStorage_JsonStorage.setAll (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\app.asar\webpack:\src\main\types\json\JsonStorage.js:58:10)
at GlobalSettings_GlobalSettings.setAll (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\app.asar\webpack:\src\main\types\settings\Settings.js:55:19)
at GlobalSettings_GlobalSettings.bootstrap (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\app.asar\webpack:\src\main\types\settings\Settings.js:87:10)
at GlobalSettings_GlobalSettings.bootstrap (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\app.asar\webpack:\src\main\types\settings\GlobalSettings.js:15:11)
at C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\app.asar\webpack:\src\main\index.js:235:12`

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and it still does not work. This happened randomly too as there are a few packages that I have that when I uninstall and reinstall it does the same for Ganache-CLI, but my CLI works. If I try to install another version of Ganache-UI it does not work either. Is there anything that I must do to fix this. Should I go to the source code, and clone it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install a previous release of Ganache through a .exe file. Apparently, the .appx installers are having problems on Windows 11. I ended up installing a very old release from 2020 that had a .exe file included with it.

That link is [v2.5.4 - JohnnyCakes Cobbler](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-ui/releases/tag/v2.5.4)

It is the most recent ui release that had a .exe installer. I do not even think that you can go the route of cloning the source code and compiling it into a .exe. From what I saw ganache-ui can only be compiled into a .appx right now.

Comment: exactly the same issue. this solved it, thank you.

Comment: No problem. I am trying to bring this issue to the attention of the Ganache team as .appx installers  are causing problems with Windows 11.